# How to find all possible number combinations that make up a specific amount

Tags: postgresql, sum, having

I'm viewing a report that's pushing back an amount which I'm wanting to find what items (when added together) make up this amount.

```
id  balance
1   400
2   315
3   481
4   5348
5   542
6   34
7   0
8   0
9   48610
10  4652
11  81
12  7
13  18964
14  346
15  6447
16  200
17  150.1
```

In the example data above, I would want to find which of these values, when added together, would make up 5778.10.

What I tried (unsuccessful):

```
SELECT id,
  ind_bal
FROM (
  SELECT sum(balance) AS ind_bal,
    id
  FROM accountbalances
  GROUP BY id
  ) bal
GROUP BY id,
  ind_bal
HAVING sum(ind_bal) = 5778.1
```

SQL Fiddle Link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e93a1/10

EDIT:

I was messing around with array_aggs, but it's still unfortunately not tying out to any results:

```
WITH agg AS (
SELECT array_agg(id) AS ids, SUM(balance) AS total_balance
FROM accountbalances
HAVING sum(balance) = 5778.1
)
SELECT unnest(ids) AS id
  FROM agg
;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a brute-force approach, and I'm sure there are better solutions.

However, if you wanted to try and see which values sum up across the given ones - one possibility is to assign each value to a group. Then, use a GROUP BY clause to sum up the values belonging to each group.

For instance, let's say we had assigned the first six letters to a group:

```
 id | balance | letter 
----+---------+--------
  1 |     400 | A
  2 |     315 | B
  3 |     481 | C
  4 |    5348 | A
  5 |     542 | B
  6 |      34 | C
```

We can then attempt to group the values together as follows:

```
select sum(balance), letter from bal group by letter;
 sum  | letter 
------+--------
  857 | B
  515 | C
 5748 | A
(3 rows)
```

If your array of data is small enough, this could work as a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the thought! Unfortunately for this scenario I wouldn't have any criteria for each individual item; it's really just the 'target amount' that I'm wanting to see what possibly adds to it. 

There's a little over 10k records that hold their own balances, but there's a mismatch between the total amounts, so I was hoping to find some function that works backwards in a way to searches all possible number combinations grouped by ID that could potentially equal the net difference between the totals.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. As I said, I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do it. Hope you get some more informative answers!